# Python seems to be ignoring the if statement within this class. What's going on?

Tags: python, debugging, if-statement

So I'm writing up a linked list class, and one of the required function is inserting at a certain position. That's simple enough, and I have the code written for it, but I've also put together an error setup to keep someone from trying to add an element at an index that isn't there:

```
def insert_element_at(self, data, position):
    position=position-1 #gets around the difference between indexing and the way we count things
    if position >= self.size:
        print("Error: Index larger than current list size")
        return 
    newnode=self.Node(data)
    current=self.header 
    for i in range (0, position): 
        current=current.nextnode 
    newnode.nextnode=current.nextnode
    current.nextnode=newnode
    self.size=self.size+1
```

I feel like this *should* work, but whenever I try to insert an element that's larger than the size of the list, the code instead tries to work all the way to the end of the list (or past it)—where it tries to stick the data into a node that doesn't exist. I get this error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'nextnode'.

And that makes sense, but it *shouldn't* be going that far at all. How can I fix this?

Here's the full code, for context: https://pastebin.com/wgTLWWsx

Comment: You're not keeping `nextnode` and `previousnode` links in sync, in this method and the other methods.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite know what you mean. That part of the code, at least, is one of the only ones that I'm sure _should_ work, since it's a direct adaptation of the function that our instructor gave us.

Comment: That part of the code doesn't do anything to update `previousnode` links, so no, it doesn't work. It might have worked for a singly-linked list, but yours is doubly-linked.

Comment: Shit, you're right! That's what I get for using the prof's single-linked list example when trying to make a doubly-linked list. I'll go back and change that. I don't think it addresses the error I asked about but it was bound to come up at some time, so this is good.

Comment: I think the problem is in your append function.
You never build the forward pointers there.
You're missing:
"newnode.previousnode.nextnode = newnode"

Comment: Holy crap, that worked! That, combined with the the other fixes pointed out here, fixed everything. Thank you so, so much!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe problem that position starts from 0 and size from 1, so position is 4 and size is 5

Comment: Size should start at 0, though, right? That's how it is in the initial constructor.

Comment: And position also starts from 0, than why do decrease it by 1 before comparing?

Comment: Oh, that one's because if someone says they want something to be put in at the 2nd item of the list, they'll put in 2. But index[2] isn't the position of the 2nd item—that would be index[1]. Hence the subtraction.

Comment: In your example position = 4 and size = 5, why do you think  your if statement should work?

Comment: You were right, it shouldn't. My bad. It turns out that I'm able to get the error message to work when I take out that -1 line, like you said that I should. So, thank you there. But "4" for position still doesn't work—everything else either enters a new node into the list or gives me an error, and I can't for the life of me figure out why 4 doesn't trigger the if statement and return an error.